# What do this code do?

Tags: javascript, cj

My client's website contains this code snipset:

```
<script>
/*DO NOT ALTER */
(function(e) {
    var t = "1775",
        n = document,
        r, i, s = {
            http: "http://cdn.mplxtms.com/s/MasterTMS.min.js",
            https: "https://secure-cdn.mplxtms.com/s/MasterTMS.min.js"
        },
        o = s[/\w+/.exec(window.location.protocol)[0]];
    i = n.createElement("script"), i.type = "text/javascript", i.async = !0, i.src = o + "#" + t, r = n.getElementsByTagName("script")[0], r.parentNode.insertBefore(i, r), i.readyState ? i.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (i.readyState === "loaded" || i.readyState === "complete") i.onreadystatechange = null
    } : i.onload = function() {
        try {
            e()
        } catch (t) {}
    }
})(function() {});
```

What do this code do ?

I googled this code but don't find answer. I only known it related with CJ affiliate.

Thanks all !

Comment: Ask your client I guess. On first glance it looks like it injects a js file into the document.

Comment: Its loading one of the above JavaScript files

Comment: thanks for your reponse ! But I googled and seen this code is common, I think someone can known.

Comment: you could remove it and test if the site still works.

Comment: help me ! I see this code is common: http://cdn.mplxtms.com/s/MasterTMS.min.js

Comment: It was repeated twice now: The code injects the js file you just linked into the page. Before it does that, it checks whether the page was loaded through http or https and changes the link accordingly.

Comment: thanks you ! but what do this file script ( http://cdn.mplxtms.com/s/MasterTMS.min.js) to do ? because i searched and seen it is common !

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the protocol includes one of either:

```
http: "http://cdn.mplxtms.com/s/MasterTMS.min.js",
https: "https://secure-cdn.mplxtms.com/s/MasterTMS.min.js"
```

JS files into the page in script tags.